# jQuery - scrollTop() sum every time I scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to adding a class when `scrollTop() < 442`. As the event didn't fire up, I tried to `console.log()` the `scrollTop()` value. The console prints out the sum of every scroll movement. For example, I scrolled 200 pixels down, I scrolled 100px up, and `console.log($('body').scrollTop())` output 300.

Here is the code:

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
    console.log($('body').scrollTop());
    if($('body').scrollTop()<442){
        $('nav').addClass('navz');

    }else{
        $('nav').removeClass('navz');
    }
});
```

I used `$('body').scroll` instead `$(window).scroll`, because `html` has `overflow:hidden`, so `$(window).scroll` doesn't work. I can't remove or change the overflow because this will change some CSS effects.

Comment: what do you mean with "the sum", you are outputing two values, log only the body's scrollTop. What's the actual element with the scroll? HTML or BODY tag? use that one not both. You say your html has overflow: hidden so there's no point adding the event listener to the HTML element.

Comment: sorry i review my code and i paste the wrong one i am going to correct it but I'm only outputting `$('body').scrollTop()` `console.log($('body').scrollTop())`

Comment: Can you create a simple jsfiddle/codepen example to reproduce your problem? I makes no sense for it print the sum but from the code you posted there's no indication of nothing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you are incorrectly using `'body'` as the selector for both the scroll event listener, as well as the scrollTop() function.

You should be using `$(window).scroll()` and `$(document).scrollTop()` instead.

Here's a working example:

```js
// The window has a scroll event, not 'body'
$(window).scroll(function() {
  
  // The document has the scrollTop fn, not 'body'
  console.log($(document).scrollTop());
  
  if ($(document).scrollTop() < 442) {
    $('nav').addClass('navz');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('navz');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```